# Display Images from media directory using media picker not working

Tags: asp.net, image, xslt, umbraco

I am using `Umbraco v6.1.6` and what I want is simply display the images from the media directory I select using media picker.

The content of media directory is as below:
[image: Media]

And I have created an XSLT file named `ImageSlider.xslt` and the content of that file are as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:umb="urn:umbraco.library"
    exclude-result-prefixes="umb"
>
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:param name="currentPage" />
<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="media" select="umb:GetMedia(1088, 0)" />
    <xsl:if test="$media">
        <img src="{$media/umbracoFile}" alt="{$media/altText}" />
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

here `1088` is the ID of the `banner` directory but it is not working at all. I am new to this.

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what `is not working at all` means in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to select the folder and list all images underneath it. At the moment, your code is just trying to display the folder. You need something like this...

In my example, I'm using a multi-node tree picker and you can select images and folders, rendering out a csv. It will loop through it all and list out all the images

```
  <xsl:for-each select="$source/value">
      <xsl:variable name="imageId" select="number(current())" />

      <xsl:if test="$imageId &gt; 0">
        <xsl:variable name="media" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($imageId, 0)" />

        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="local-name($media) = 'Image'">
            <xsl:call-template name="ImageBox">
              <xsl:with-param name="imageId" select="$imageId"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="local-name($media) = 'Folder'">
            <xsl:call-template name="LoopFolders">
              <xsl:with-param name="folderId" select="$imageId"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:if>   

  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="LoopFolders">
    <xsl:param name="folderId"/>
    <xsl:variable name="media" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($folderId, 0)" />
    <xsl:variable name="alt" select="$media/@nodeName" />

    <div id="gallery">
        <xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($folderId, true())/Image">
            <xsl:call-template name="ImageBox">
       <xsl:with-param name="imageId" select="number(@id)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</div>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="ImageBox">
    <xsl:param name="imageId"/>

    <xsl:if test="$imageId &gt; 0">
        <xsl:variable name="media" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($imageId, 0)" />
        <xsl:if test="$media">
            <xsl:variable name="url" select="$media/umbracoFile" />
            <xsl:variable name="width" select="$media/umbracoWidth" />
            <xsl:variable name="height" select="$media/umbracoHeight" />
            <xsl:variable name="alt" select="$media/@nodeName" />
            <img src="{$url}" alt="{$alt}" width="{$width}" height="{$height}" />           
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```